# Skype Cannot Connect Through Squid3 Proxy Server

Tags: linux, proxy, skype

Been trying to figure this out for a while to no avail...

I have a squid3 proxy server setup on a separate machine on a different network. I'm using the digest user protocol to store access usernames and such for the squid3 server. The config file looks as follows:

```
auth_param digest program /usr/lib/squid3/digest_file_auth -c /etc/squid3/passwords
auth_param digest realm proxy
acl authenticated proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow authenticated
http_port 8888
access_log /squid3_logs/access.log squid
cache_store_log /squid3_logs/store.log
cache_log /squid3_logs/cache.log
```

I can connect via my web browser with no issue at all (it prompts me for username/password, I enter it, and then have access). However, if I try to force Skype to use the proxy configuration, it sits at the spinning refresh icon forever, never connecting. I really just want all ports and services allowed through the squid server for each user, which is what I thought I had configured, but apparently not. My Linux version is Ubuntu Desktop 14.04 LTS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jnrprimo I'm pretty sure it does use port 80 and 443 as default... I know its not a Skype issue, I had a friend set one up for me earlier with the same Skype settings and it worked. I accidentally deleted that though, and can't seem to configure my own.

Answer (score 1):

Skype can use either a HTTPS or a SOCKS5 proxy, and not a HTTP proxy, which is what Squid is. Squid supposedly has support for HTTPS, but I couldn't figure out an easy way to get it to work. What I did was I installed dante-server, configured it and then configured Skype to only use a SOCKS5 proxy.

I first installed dante-server

```
sudo apt-get install dante-server
```

Then I pasted this configuration into /etc/danted.conf (change the proxy port, and put in your network address):

```
logoutput: syslog
logoutput: /var/log/sockd.log

internal: eth0 port = <your proxy port here>
external: eth0

method: username none #rfc931

user.privileged: proxy
user.notprivileged: nobody
user.libwrap: nobody

client pass {
from: <your network address here>/24 port 1-65535 to: 0.0.0.0/0
}

pass {
from: <your network address here>/24 to: 0.0.0.0/0
protocol: tcp udp
}
```

Start, or restart, dante-server

```
service danted start
```

Then configure Skype to only use a SOCKS5 proxy, via the registry. I only did this to prevent Skype from connecting directly. If you don't mind Skype trying to connect directly, then you can just configure the proxy settings in the GUI (change the server address and port).

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Skype\Phone]
"ProxySetting"="SOCKS5"
"ProxyAddress"="<your proxy server ip address here>:<your proxy port here>"
```

Start Skype, and it should now connect through the proxy.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Unfortunately, I tried that exactly, with Skype still sitting at the spinning refresh icon. Any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like you have a different issue then. Assuming you have dante-server setup correctly, you should be able to run Wireshark on the computer with Skype and watch the SOCKS session traffic, so that you can further troubleshoot. You can use `host <your proxy server ip address here> and port <your proxy port here>` for the capture filter and `socks` for the display filter. I'd also use the browser, with the proxy settings configured, to help troubleshoot.